# reading lines from java socket with inconsistent line terminators

Tags: java, readline, bufferedreader, terminator

I am using BufferedReader#readLine() to get text lines from a TCP/IP socket.

During the same session, my server sometimes sends lines terminated with \r\n and sometimes it send lines terminated just with \n.

This behavior is not under my control :(

The Javadoc for readLine() says:

> "A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed."

Unfortunately, that does not seem to work (at least on Windows). It only "knows" to read lines ending with \r\n.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Adrian.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code, because it definitely works. Execute the following code: `String test = "first\nsecond\rthird\r\nfourth";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(test));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }`

Comment: Do you mean that on windows if you receive line-feed only, readline is not correctly recognizing them?

Comment: @Rob HYes. readLine() hangs forever, or if the socket has a defined timeout, then a SocketTimeoutException is thrown :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a simple socket client and tested against a netcat server.
The issue is that the netcat server always sends in UTF-8 and the client cannot expect UTF-16 for example.

Here is the client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class LineReader {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("usage: java LineReader charset url");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            final String charset = args[0];
            final URI url = new URI(args[1]);
            final String host = url.getHost();
            final int port = url.getPort();
            final Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), charset));
            while (true) {
                final String line = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Bottom line: there is no issue with the readLine method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the line.separator property of the underlaying OS: You could do it as follows:

```
static final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty ( "line.separator" );
```

Comment: My client always run on Windows, so the line.separator is definitely \r\n. The issue is that the server sometimes sends \r\n and sometimes sends \n. You could try that by running nc -lp 2000 (using cygwin on Windows). In this case, nc (netcat) sends lines terminated by \n, and these are not recognized by readLine().

Comment: My mistake... Seems like an encoding issue. I will post the answer later.